# How to write out Capital Words in String?

Tags: string, visual-studio-2012, uppercase, words, sentence

***Im using Visual Studio 2012.***

I need to write in a sentence and then check how many words in that sentence starts with a uppercase letter(A,G,Z,U...)-ok I did that,now **I need to write out the words that start with uppercase letter**

For example:"Hi there Please Help me With this QUESTION",I need my program to say:
" *5 words start with uppercase letters and those words are:Hi Please Help With QUESTION* "

Here is what I have done already(counting the words that start with uppercase letter):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define lenght 20
int main(){
char sentence[lenght];
int i,n=0,num;
printf("\nWrite a sentence: ");
gets(sentence);
if(sentence[0]>='A' && sentence[0]<='Z'){
            n++;
        }
num=strlen(sentence);
for(i=0;i<num;i++){
    if(!(sentence[i]>='A' && sentence[i]<='Z' || sentence[i]>='a' && sentence[i]<='z')){
        if(sentence[i+1]>='A' && sentence[i+1]<='Z'){
        n++;
        }}}
printf("\nNum of words that start with uppercase letter is:%d \n",n);
return 0;
}
```

This Works but I have no idea how to write out the words that start with uppercase letters,I tried something with strcpy but that didnt work,I also tried doing it with just printf but that didnt work either.
Help pls!
P.S Thanks for all the help!

Comment: "... starts with a uppercase letter(A,G,Z,U...)" - examples of uppercase letters? Seriously? Hands up anyone here who doesn't know what an uppercase letter is :-)

Answer (score 0):

For any character position that contains a letter, you can check to see whether that is the start of the word by looking at the *previous* character position. If that is *also* a letter, then you are not at the start of a word.

Comment: I Know how to check if it is a letter,but I dont Know how to check if it isnt a letter.I started with: if(sentence !=)...but i didnt know how to continue.

Comment: if(sentence[i]>='A' && sentence[i]<='Z' || sentence[i]>='a' && sentence[i]<='z')-this is how I check if a character IS a letter.

Comment: You can do it two ways: One is to use `!`, so `if (!(sentence[i] >= 'A' && sentence[i] <= 'Z'))`, the other is to reverse the whole test using [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws): `if (sentence[i] < 'A' || sentence[i] > 'Z')`

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should probably do is to define what the start of a word is. Only then can you figure out if it's uppercase.

For example, my immediate (naive) thoughts were that the first letter of a word would either be at the beginning of the text, or immediately follow some whitespace of some description (newline, space, tab, and so on).

If that were the case, it would be a simple matter of counting how many times you see one of those whitespace characters followed immediately by an uppercase letter. The pseudo-code for such a beast would be something like:

```
def countUppercasedWords (sentence):
    count = 0
    for i = 0 to sentence.lastCharIndex - 1:
        if sentence[i] in '<whitespace>' and sentence[i+1] in 'A..Z':
            count = count + 1
    return count
```

Now it may be that the definition I've used in too simplistic (SUCH AS WITH THIS VERY SENTENCE) since I haven't considered the opening parenthesis to be whitespace.

But you have to strike a balance so that YOU'RE not picking up false positives such as in this sentence, where `YOU` and `RE` may be considered separate words.

Perhaps a viable approach may be to have a list of valid words that you can check against (i.e., a full dictionary, suitably lowercased). Then, for every position in the text, grab the maximum number of characters (again, lowercased for checking) that forms a valid word and check the first character of that, before advancing that many characters.

If you cannot *see* a valid word at the current position, just advance to the next character and keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems you use C, not C++, right?

You need a space to store all these words. You should use dynamically allocated or large enough string array. The second method is simpler, so I would use it.

```
#define MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH 1024
#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH 64
#define MAX_WORDS 32

. . .

char sentence[MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH];
char words[MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
int word_count;
char* current_char;
size_t word_length;

gets(sentence);
current_char = sentence;
while(1) {
    /* Skip white spaces */
    while(*current_char != '\0' && isspace(*current_char))
        current_char++;

    if(*current_char == '\0')
        break;

    if(isupper(*current_char)) {
        /* Store word in the array and increment word's count.
        word_length = 0;

        while(current_char[word_length] != '\0' && !isspace(current_char[word_length])) {
            words[word_count][word_length] = current_char[word_length];
            word_length++;
        }

        word[word_count][word_length] = '\0';
        word_count++;
    }
    else {
        /* Skip word without first upper letter */
        while(*current_char != '\0' && !isspace(*current_char))
            current_char++;
    }
}
. . .
printf("%d words are found and these words are:\n", word_count);
for(int i = 0; i < word_count; i++)
     printf("%s\n", words[i]);
```